# Having trouble saving items

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the code below I would like to have the health of the zombie save and each time I shoot subtract 50 from the health of the zombie. The health of the zombie should be 100 and each shot should take 50 from it. I'm having trouble trying to get it to save. Instead I have to just print it.

```
shoot = -50
zombie_hp = -100

def zombie1(shoot, zombie_hp):
    return shoot - zombie_hp

def attack():   
    print "You see a zombie in the distance."
    attack = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    print zombie1(zombie_hp, shoot)
    if attack == "shoot" and shoot == -50:
        print "Zombie health 50/100"
        attack2 = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
        print zombie1(zombie_hp, shoot)
        if attack == "shoot":
            print "Zombie health 0/100 (Zombie dies)"
attack()
```

Comment: *"I'm having trouble"* is **not** a helpful problem statement. What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? You don't appear to be making any attempt to *"get it to save"*. You also never *assign* the value returned by `zombie1`. If you want to retain the state of the "zombie", consider making a `Zombie` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the following:

```
damage = 50
zombie_hp = 100

def attack():
    global zombie_hp #1
    zombie_hp -= damage #2
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%zombie_hp #3
    if zombie_hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

print "You see a zombie in the distance."
while zombie_hp > 0: #4
    user_input = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    if user_input == 'shoot':
        attack()
```

1. use global zombie_hp to change the outter zombie_hp, or else it will not change
2. this will subtract the damage from the zombie_hp
3. this will print the current hp of the zombie in a proper way. no need to type it yourself.
4. This part will keep the program running until the zombie is dead

---

As stated by @jonrsharpe, consider making a Zombie class.

Like so:

```
class Zombie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 100

def attack(target):
    target.hp -= DAMAGE
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target.hp
    if target.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"


DAMAGE = 50
zombie1 = Zombie()

print "You see a zombie in the distance."
while zombie1.hp > 0:
    user_input = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    if user_input == 'shoot':
        attack(zombie1)
```